# pl/sql regex verification

Tags: sql, regex, plsql

How to verify a string that only permits numbers letters and the characters like '.', '/', '_', '-' and only permit 40 characters.

I was doing something like this `REGEXP_LIKE(path, '[a-zA-Z0-9_./-]{2,40}$')` but is not working good.

Can anyone help me with this regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it won't limit to 40 characters because it isn't anchored to the beginning of the string.  Try:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(path, '^[a-zA-Z0-9_./-]{2,40}$')
```

Other than that I don't see anything glaringly wrong with it, assuming of course that you do mean for the minimum length to be 2 characters.

Comment: It won't limit to 40 without the `^` anchor because then it will match any time the 40 characters at the end of the string match; there could be 5K of gibberish before that and the regex would still find a match.

Answer (score 2):

May be you need to add beginning of line special character `^`, i.e.: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_./-]{2,40}$`